# Binary Search Tree - Search Fcn in Python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to implement a search function into my `BinaryTree` class. Basically, I return a `True` value from the recursive function `_search`, but it keeps running the rest of the loop instead of breaking out of the `_search` method. I thought `return` was supposed to break out of the method? Below is the output and code.

OUTPUT:

```
1
2
4
5
3
 
1
2
4
5
3
```

CODE:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BinaryTree(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = Node(root)

    def print_tree(self):
        """Print out all tree nodes
        as they are visited in
        a pre-order traversal."""
        
        return ""

    def preorder_print(self, start, traversal):
        """Helper method - use this to create a 
        recursive print solution."""
        return traversal


    def search(self, find_val):
        """Return True if the value
        is in the tree, return
        False otherwise."""
        return self._search(self.root, find_val)

        
    def _search(self, current_node, find_val):
        """Helper method - use this to create a 
        recursive search solution."""
        # check if current node = val
        print(current_node.value)
        if current_node.value == find_val:
            return True 
        # 
        elif current_node.left or current_node.right:
            self._search(current_node.left, find_val)
            self._search(current_node.right, find_val)
        return False
        



# Set up tree
tree = BinaryTree(1)
tree.root.left = Node(2)
tree.root.right = Node(3)
tree.root.left.left = Node(4)
tree.root.left.right = Node(5)

# Test search
# Should be True
tree.search(4)
print(" ")
# Should be False
tree.search(6)

# Test print_tree
# Should be 1-2-4-5-3
print tree.print_tree()
```

Comment: The `return` statement in python, as with most programming languages, only returns from the current function back to the calling function. It is no different in the case of recursive functions where the calling function is often the same function.

Comment: Your search function is incorrect. 1) if current node is None, return False, 2)  if current_node.value == find_val then return True, 3) return the result of searching the left subtree or right subtree based upon current_node.value is less than or greater than find_val and return that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that given input is not a Binary Search Tree, it's a Binary Tree.

For BST all child nodes on right side should be greater than root and all nodes on left side should be smaller than root.

But for this binary tree solution, problem is below:

```
        elif current_node.left or current_node.right:
            self._search(current_node.left, find_val)
            self._search(current_node.right, find_val)
```

So if either left or right node is there, you are recursively searching on both sides and not returning anything. So you need to change it to as below:

```
        elif current_node.left:
            return self._search(current_node.left, find_val)
        elif current_node.right:
            return self._search(current_node.right, find_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Vijay said, you have to change the following code snippet:

```py
elif current_node.left or current_node.right:
    self._search(current_node.left, find_val)
    self._search(current_node.right, find_val)
```

To something similar to the following code:

```py
        if current_node.value == find_val:
            return True
        if current_node.left:
            if self._search(current_node.left, find_val) == True:
                return True
        if current_node.right:
            if self._search(current_node.right, find_val) == True:
                return True

        return False
```

Which worked for me in the entire example:

```py
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


class BinaryTree(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = Node(root)

    def print_tree(self):
        """Print out all tree nodes
        as they are visited in
        a pre-order traversal."""

        return ""

    def preorder_print(self, start, traversal):
        """Helper method - use this to create a
        recursive print solution."""
        return traversal

    def search(self, find_val):
        """Return True if the value
        is in the tree, return
        False otherwise."""
        return self._search(self.root, find_val)

    def _search(self, current_node, find_val):
        """Helper method - use this to create a
        recursive search solution."""
        # check if current node = val
        print(current_node.value)
        if current_node.value == find_val:
            return True
        if current_node.left:
            if self._search(current_node.left, find_val) == True:
                return True
        if current_node.right:
            if self._search(current_node.right, find_val) == True:
                return True

        return False


# Set up tree
tree = BinaryTree(1)
tree.root.left = Node(2)
tree.root.right = Node(3)
tree.root.left.left = Node(4)
tree.root.left.right = Node(5)

# Test search
# Should be True
print("Should be True")
print(tree.search(4))
print(tree.search(1))
print(tree.search(2))
print(tree.search(3))
print(tree.search(5))

print("Should be False")
# Should be False
print(tree.search(6))
print(tree.search(0))
print(tree.search(8))
```

### Output

```py
Should be True
1
2
4
True
1
True
1
2
True
1
2
4
5
3
True
1
2
4
5
True

Should be False
1
2
4
5
3
False
1
2
4
5
3
False
1
2
4
5
3
False
```